# Recalling WebRequest.create

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am calling the code below every 100ms.

```
private void First_Request()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connection Request");

    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(LOGIN_SERVER); 

    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
    MAC = GetMacAddress().ToString();  

    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
    {
        id = ID,
        macaddress = MAC
    });


    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        var result_header = httpResponse.Headers;

        string cookie = httpResponse.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie");

        if (result.Contains("true"))
        {
            ConnectionIs = true;
        }
        else if (result.Contains("false"))
        {
            ConnectionIs = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know if the connection would be disconnected then make new connection whenever the line

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(LOGIN_SERVER);
```

is called in every 100ms to send an ID and MAC address to the server.

If it the connection is lost, how am I suppose to maintain the connection?

Or is there possible ways instead of using WebRequest.Create?

Comment: HttpWebRequest uses a connection pool to make requests. It is connections in this pool that are connected and disconnected. Web requests then borrow connections from the pool.

Comment: So it is disconnected when var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(LOGIN_SERVER); is called again and then connected again by below codes. Am I right? I want a result which would not be disconnected from the server. Any suggestions would be a great help

Comment: If you want a continuous connection, you may want to open a `Socket`.

Comment: If you really want to see what is going on use a sniffer like fiddler or wireshark.  The sniffer will show you the http packets as well as the individual TCP packets.  In the TCP you will see when the connection is opened and closed.  I believe the TCP will stay open until the WebRequest is closed.  Also believe the the Create opens a new connection.  It would be equivalent to having two IE application going to the same URL.  If you run an app on the URL on one IE the 2nd is not going to run the app.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Now I know that it is making new connection so I am finding new ways to solve it. Thanks for recommending Socket. It gave me a new idea of using cURL. If it doesn't work I would probably use Socket. Thank you guys. Have a great day.